# Implementing a Windows script

Tags: c#, windows, scripting, windows-scripting

Hi
I would like to create a script which loads a program on my windows based computer, clicks on one of its buttons, and checks the data inside it (it gets its data from the web). Should I do that in C#? Any example out there?

The program contacts the web and displays information. I would like to get notified when that data has changed.

UPDATE: I've learned that the application doesn't contact a web-service using [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com/). This means I have to load the windows application, click the button and look there. How can I do such a thing? I know it is disruptive, and still I would like to do that.

Comment: Why do you need the script to load the program when the program can run on its own ? Can you be more clear?

Comment: @Searock I want the script to check if the data within the program has changed (the data is web-based)

Answer (score 2):

You need to download [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/about.html) to see what http(s) the program is using.

And once you come to know about http(s) used, you can use the [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) and [WebResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webresponse.aspx) classes for making request to the server.

Comment: This sounds like a good approach. I've installed Wireshark but haven't been able to understand how I can find the relevant http(s). There's a lot of packets. What should I look for? Is there a way to know that app "Source"?

Answer (score 1):

The method you described in checking for changes is quite disruptive: the script you intend to write needs to load the program and **clicks** the button. The loading and clicking is enough to disrupt whatever you are doing when the script runs.

I suggest changing the method to access the web directly to check for changes, and only displays a notification (WPF or whatever method you are comfortable with) when the data changes.

Comment: Unfortunately, the application contacts a private web api which I'm not aware of. Is there an easy way to check from what web address the window-application retrieves his data from?

Comment: If your main intention is to get notified of the changes, then you do not need to know the web api;  all you need to do is to access the page via http(s), pull the data as a string and compare it with the last copy your script previously retrieved. If the page is quite big, then you may need to narrow the comparison via xpath first.

Comment: but how can I know to which http(s) they are contacting? Is there a small tool to see to which http(s) my computer is now contacting?